# C++ Why does this code compile?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to understand why does the following code compile?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
   int cin;
   cin >> cin;
   cout << "cin" << cin;
   return 0;
}
```

How is the compiler able to distinguish in the statement: "cin >> cin"?

Comment: [Compile with warnings.](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/tgFspjAMCsbzNGCY) It helps to see [what's going on](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/336xbhcz.aspx).

Comment: The local variable `cin` is "preferred" over the global variable `cin`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you run the program, you'll notice that it never waits for input.

It doesn't distinguish anything – you're right-shifting the `int` by its own value.
(And that value is indeterminate, so the program is undefined.)

If you increase the warning level of your compiler, you should see "Warning: statement has no effect" or something to that effect.

Comment: I believe that the OP wants to know how the compiler distinguishes between the variable `int cin` and the variable `istream cin` (i.e., how the compiler determines which one should be used in each part of the statement `cin >> cin`).

Comment: Thank you, now I understand.

Answer (score 0):

To add on to molbdnilo's answer:

When you are using the statement `using namespace std;`, you are telling the compiler that for all variables in the current scope, loop up the identifier in current scope, if not, look up in the parent scope, **until the look up reaches global scope and still unable to find the identifier**, then it will try to find it in the **namespace you are using**.

After you declared `int cin`, everything that is called `cin` in the main function will be the local int `cin` not the std::cin, so all of your codes are just left shifting `cin` and shifting `"cin"` by `cin` amount of bits.